# PowerBI measure or calculated column to look at the last unitname based on actiondate grouped by eventidx

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns, measure

I am looking for a way to either create a measure or calculated column in PBI desktop to get the last unitname per event_idx based on the latest actiondate. Below is a picture with data attached.

[image]

As you can see, there are many updates to a single event, so I would like to know the best way to take the last unitname based on the action date field and group it by event_idx. If this was sql I could do this easily but I am not as familiar with dax so I am struggling with the correct formulas and syntax.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the measure to display the result only in relevant rows, then use this

```
Measure1 =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( tbl[UNITNAME] ),
    FILTER (
        tbl,
        tbl[ACTIONDATE]
            = CALCULATE ( MAX ( tbl[ACTIONDATE] ), ALLEXCEPT ( tbl, tbl[EVENT_IDX] ) )
    )
)
```

If you want the measure to display the result per idx, then use this

```
Measure2 =
VAR _idx =
    MAX ( tbl[EVENT_IDX] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( tbl[UNITNAME] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( tbl ),
            tbl[EVENT_IDX] = _idx
                && tbl[ACTIONDATE]
                    = CALCULATE ( MAX ( tbl[ACTIONDATE] ), ALLEXCEPT ( tbl, tbl[EVENT_IDX] ) )
        )
    )
```

[image: s1]

Comment: thank you for the response. I believe that first measure is exactly what I need as far as a table of the information, but let me ask you, how can I put that measure in like a column chart? I need to show the last crew that touched it where a column from a related table expired.